# How to get unused memory back from the large object heap LOH from multiple managed apps?

Tags: c#, .net, garbage-collection

While talking to a colleague about a particular group of apps using up nearly 1.5G memory on startup... he pointed me to a very good link on [.NET production debugging](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms954594.aspx)

The part that has me puzzled is ...

> For example, if you allocate 1 MB of
>   memory to a single block, the large
>   object heap expands to 1 MB in size.
>   When you free this object, the large
>   object heap does not decommit the
>   virtual memory, so the heap stays at 1
>   MB in size. If you allocate another
>   500-KB block later, the new block is
>   allocated within the 1 MB block of
>   memory belonging to the large object
>   heap. During the process lifetime, the
>   large object heap always grows to hold
>   all the large block allocations
>   currently referenced, but never
>   shrinks when objects are released,
>   even if a garbage collection occurs.
>   Figure 2.4 on the next page shows an
>   example of a large object heap.

Now let's say we have a fictional app that creates a flurry of large objects ( > 85KB), so the large object heap grows lets say to 200 Meg. Now lets say we have 10 such app instances running.. so that 2000 Megs allocated. Now is this memory never given back to the OS until the process shuts down... (is what I understood)

Are there any gaps in my understanding? How do we get back unused memory in the various LOHeaps ; we don't create the perfect storm of OutOfMemoryExceptions ?

**Update:** From Marc's response, I wanted to clarify that the LOH objects are not referenced - the large objects are use-n-throw - however the heap doesn't shrink even though the heap is relatively empty post the initial surge.

**Update#2:** Just including a code snippet (exaggerated but gets the point across I think).. I see an OutOfMemoryException around the time the Virtual memory hits the 1.5G mark on my machine (1.7G on another).. From [Eric L.'s blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/ericlippert/archive/2009/06/08/out-of-memory-does-not-refer-to-physical-memory.aspx), 'process memory can be visualized as a massive file on disk..' - this result is thus unexpected. The machines in this instance had GBs of free space on the HDD. Does the PageFile.sys OS file (or related settings) impose any restrictions?

```
        static float _megaBytes;
        static readonly int BYTES_IN_MB = 1024*1024;

        static void BigBite()
        {
           try
           {
              var list = new List<byte[]>();
              int i = 1;

              for (int x = 0; x < 1500; x++)
              {
                 var memory = new byte[BYTES_IN_MB + i];
                 _megaBytes += memory.Length / BYTES_IN_MB;
                 list.Add(memory);
                 Console.WriteLine("Allocation #{0} : {1}MB now", i++, _megaBytes);
              }
           }
           catch (Exception e)
           {  Console.WriteLine("Boom! {0}", e); // I put a breakpoint here to check the console
              throw;
           }
        }
       static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            BigBite();
            Console.WriteLine("Check VM now!"); Console.ReadLine();
            _megaBytes = 0;

            ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(delegate { BigBite(); });
            ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(delegate { BigBite(); });
            Console.ReadLine();   // will blow before it reaches here
        }
```

Answer (score 7):

There is a clarification I would like to make first. 
- Assuming you are running app as a 32bit app, the VA space available for your process is only 2 GB , 3GB if you enabled large address space switch, so even if you have HUGE page file, it doesn't matter if you are 32bit process, it matters if you run 64bit, where you have huge address space.

- Object with size > **85000 bytes** are allocated on LOH, note it is **85000 bytes** not 85K, it is also implementation details that could change.
  Now, back to your question.
  The GC will un-commit the LOH segments that are not used in 2 situations 
  1- When the memory pressure on the machine is high ( ~95-98% )
  2- When it fails to satisfy new allocation requests, it will decommit the unused pages in the LOH

so you will get back the memory in one of these cases.
The fact that you are hitting an OOM before reaching the 2GB limit could mean you have VA fragmentation, VA fragmentation occur when you don't have continuous VA address space to satisfy new allocation, for example  you ask for 8KB segment, and you don't have 2 consecutive pages in your VA ( assuming page size is 4 K)

you can use !vamap debugger extension in Debugging tools for windows to validate this.

Hope this helps
Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Well, if you really have this kind of allocation pattern, you could move your large objects into another appdomain - when you decide to free all of the large objects, release the appdomain and the heap for that appdomain will be released.

Answer (score 3):

If the LOH wants to keep memory, that is up to the LOH - however, don't forget that `OutOfMemoryException` is per-process, since really the hard disk is the limiting factor for virtual memory. Eric Lippert [blogged about this](http://blogs.msdn.com/ericlippert/archive/2009/06/08/out-of-memory-does-not-refer-to-physical-memory.aspx) recently. Of course, that doesn't prevent it getting poor performance from all the paging...

Comment: Will update the question, The LOH objects themselves are use-n-throw in this case.. once they've served their purpose, the LOH objects have been freed, but the heap doesn't shrink. Consider a component that does some serialization of objects before sending it down a pipe : in this case you allocate say 200 Megs as byte arrays, which are garbage after the data has been transmited.

Comment: I'm not sure the edit changes anything. The point I was trying to make is that having a 200MB ball and chain isn't *necessarily* a problem. Most of it will likely move out of main memory due to inactivity...

Comment: Thanks for the link.. attached a code snippet that confuses me further but is similar to the issue that started this thread. Your thoughts as always are much appreciated. Thanks for the work you do on this forum...